# AWS connection to Neptune from VPC to VPC over a transit gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-neptune

I'm looking for recommendations on connecting to a Neptune cluster in AWS from a VPC that the Neptune cluster does *not* exist in. I'm thinking if I have a transit gateway as an intermediary bridge between the 2 VPCs I'll be able to proxy the connection through so connectivity is successful.

I need this for reads and writes. Is this an acceptable approach for a production-grade env? In addition, I'm expecting to hit the REST endpoint I think from a client-based application once the request gets into the VPC containing the Neptune cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transit Gateway would be a fine production approach here.  [VPC Peering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html) between the two VPCs would also work well for production systems.  There is also a [reference architecture](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dbs-refarch-graph/tree/master/src/connecting-using-a-load-balancer) for using a Network Load Balancer or Application Load Balancer.  If you have issues, you want to make sure your [security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/security-vpc-security-group.html) and [routing tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/vpc-peering-routing.html) are configured correctly.  Sending an HTTPS request to the [Status endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-status.html) is the easiest way to test your connectivity to Neptune.

Comment: Thanks Brian! I'll play around with it and see where I get.